# Can you set a navbar's edit button in Interface Builder?

Tags: cocoa-touch, interface-builder

It's easy enough to set up a table view to allow editing. Just add one line to your UITableViewController:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

This line adds an edit button on the nav bar that will change the table to editing mode and change its button text to "Done" while editing.

Is it possible to set this up in Interface Builder? I see that you can add a UIBarButtonItem and can set its "Identifier" to "Edit", but I don't see the expected behavior.

BTW, what does the "Identifier" in the Attributes panel do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add UIBarButtonItems in Interface Builder, and they should work.

The identifier lets you use a preset button (like Edit or Reload), or you can choose Custom and make your own button.

**EDIT:** I may be able to help further if you could explain how UIBarButtonItems added through IB don't work.

**UPDATE:** UIViewController.editButtonItem is a special method that returns a UIBarButtonItem that invokes the view's setEditing method. You can achieve the same effect by creating a method that does the same thing and connecting the selector to your UIBarButtonItem in IB.

In your header file:

```
- IBAction edit:(id)sender;
```

and in your implementation file:

```
- (IBAction) edit:(id)sender {
    [self setEditing:YES animated:YES];
}
```

then connect the selector to the UIBarButtonItem.

However, you might not be able to create this connection in the default Navigation-Based Application template since the Table View is in a separate file.

Comment: - New project: Navigation-Based Application.
- RootViewController.m: uncomment viewDidLoad and the self.nav... line 
- Run. There's no table data, but click Edit to see that it changes

Can you recomment the line and get the behavior by changes to MainWindow.xib? Or is it only set programmatically?

Comment: So how can you create an `editButtonItem` specifically in Interface Builder? IMHO you have chosen to answer a different (trivial) question back at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: http://blog.tmro.net/2009/05/uitabbarbuttonitem-did-not-change-its.html

If you want your button to be able to change its label dynamically make sure you use a custom identifier otherwise its title will be immutable.

Answer (score 0):

We still can't seem to do this specifically in Interface Builder as of Xcode 9.4.1. It's very easy to do in code, though.

You don't need to set up the button in IB at all. Simply add this code in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
```

That automatically sets up the Edit button, which turns to Done so the user can end editing.

To do anything custom associated with the editing process, override the view controller's `setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool)` method.

For example, if you have a table view whose editing needs to be turned on and off, you can do this:

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
    tableView.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
}
```

*Make sure to call `super.setEditing` here.*

Note: if you're using a `UITableViewController`, `setEditing` is already set up in the super class to handle the table view. You don't need to override it, unless you have other custom code you want to include when editing is enabled/disabled.